# Error saving update on Participant Status

Tags: error

After the latest Core update I receive an error when trying to save an updated Event Participant Status.  The record ultimately does save, but throws an error (details below).  I'm not sure how to interpret it.  Any indication where I should be looking, or what is going wrong?

**DETAILS:**

- CiviCRM version 5.69.3
- WordPress version 6.4.3
- Active theme: Hello Elementor (version 2.4.2.1642712871)
- PHP version 8.1.23

## Error Details

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 90 of the file /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/WorkflowMessage/WorkflowMessage.php. Error message: Uncaught TypeError: Civi\WorkflowMessage\WorkflowMessage::importAll(): Argument #1 ($model) must be of type Civi\WorkflowMessage\WorkflowMessageInterface, array given, called in /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php on line 358 and defined in /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/WorkflowMessage/WorkflowMessage.php:90
Stack trace:
#0 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php(358): Civi\WorkflowMessage\WorkflowMessage::importAll(Array, Array)
#1 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php(422): CRM_Core_BAO_MessageTemplate::renderTemplateRaw(Array)
#2 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/MessageTemplate.php(126): CRM_Core_BAO_MessageTemplate::sendTemplate(Array)
#3 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_message_template_send(Array)
#4 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(156): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke(Array)
#5 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(79): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Array)
#6 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(136): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe('MessageTemplate', 'send', Array)
#7 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/de.systopia.eventmessages/CRM/Eventmessages/SendMail.php(100): civicrm_api3('MessageTemplate', 'send', Array)
#8 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/de.systopia.eventmessages/CRM/Eventmessages/Logic.php(305): CRM_Eventmessages_SendMail::sendMessageTo(Array)
#9 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/de.systopia.eventmessages/CRM/Eventmessages/Logic.php(85): CRM_Eventmessages_Logic::processStatusChange(40, 20, 21, 605)
#10 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/de.systopia.eventmessages/eventmessages.php(104): CRM_Eventmessages_Logic::recordPostCommit(605, Object(CRM_Event_BAO_Participant))
#11 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(288): eventmessages_civicrm_postCommit('edit', 'Participant', 605, Object(CRM_Event_BAO_Participant), NULL)
#12 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/WordPress.php(136): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks(Array, 'civicrm_postCom...', 5, 'edit', 'Participant', 605, Object(CRM_Event_BAO_Participant), NULL, NULL)
#13 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(326): CRM_Utils_Hook_WordPress->invokeViaUF(5, 'edit', 'Participant', 605, Object(CRM_Event_BAO_Participant), NULL, NULL, 'civicrm_postCom...')
#14 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(251): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent), 'hook_civicrm_po...', Object(Civi\Core\UnoptimizedEventDispatcher))
#15 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(73): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners(Array, 'hook_civicrm_po...', Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent))
#16 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(263): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent), 'hook_civicrm_po...')
#17 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(401): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch('hook_civicrm_po...', Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent))
#18 [internal function]: CRM_Utils_Hook::postCommit('edit', 'Participant', 605, Object(CRM_Event_BAO_Participant))
#19 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Frame.php(198): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Frame.php(148): Civi\Core\Transaction\Frame->invokeCallbacks(2)
#21 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php(103): Civi\Core\Transaction\Frame->finish()
#22 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Transaction.php(126): Civi\Core\Transaction\Manager->dec()
#23 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/BAO/Participant.php(253): CRM_Core_Transaction->commit()
#24 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Participant.php(1003): CRM_Event_BAO_Participant::create(Array)
#25 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Participant.php(808): CRM_Event_Form_Participant->submit(Array)
#26 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(625): CRM_Event_Form_Participant->postProcess()
#27 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(153): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#28 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(120): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Participant), 'upload')
#29 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Participant), 'upload')
#30 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Participant), 'upload')
#31 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(355): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle('upload')
#32 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/Tab.php(100): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#33 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/Tab.php(158): CRM_Event_Page_Tab->edit()
#34 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(322): CRM_Event_Page_Tab->run(Array, NULL)
#35 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)
#36 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)
#37 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)
#38 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')
#39 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#40 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#41 /home/[MYDOMAIN]/www/www/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action('toplevel_page_C...')
#42 {main}
thrown

Answer (score 2):

Note this was fixed in the latest 5.69 point release (5.69.5)